# How come my request to send Firebase notification to a topic is not working (HTTP POST)?

Tags: php, curl, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

Extremely grateful for any help with this.. all I want to do is use my php code to send notifications to all users subscribed to topic "global". Does anyone know why it might not work? Since I want everyone using the app to get the notifications, I will subscribe everyone (unless there is a better way). Here is my php to try to send the notification to my topic global:

```
<?php
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'hidden...hidden' );

    $msg = array
    (
        'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
        'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1
    );

    $fields = array
    (
        'to'            => "/topics/global",
        'data'          => $msg,
        'priority'      => 'high'
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
?>
```

I am lacking knowledge but from the $result echo it didn't look like any failure message. This is what I got:

```
{"message_id":7591682951632927615}
```

In my Firebase console, I cannot even see the topic "global" so I can't test that sending to the topic works on my device. From what I read online, it could take awhile for a subscribed topic to appear in the console. **Just to clarify, sending notifications to all devices using user segment set to the App works in the console!**

Is there anything that I can do to verify that my app is actually subscribing users to the topic "global"? Maybe this is the problem. Here is the relevant swift code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("applicationReceivedRemoteMessage")
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/global")
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

    /*
     // Print message ID.
     if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
     print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
     }

     // Print full message.
     print(userInfo)
     */
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {

        print("GOT IN HERE")

        var pushNotificationMessage = ""
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = alert["message"] as? NSString {
                    pushNotificationMessage = message as String
                }
            } else if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
                pushNotificationMessage = alert as String
            }
        }

        let notificationAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: pushNotificationMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        })
        defaultAction.setValue(Constants.activePushNotificationOKColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")

        notificationAlert.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(notificationAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: [This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) uses a slightly different URL: `fcm` instead of `gcm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a `notification`, store the parameters in `notification`, not data:

```
$fields = array
(
    'to'            => "/topics/global",
    'notification'  => $msg, // <= CHANGED
    'priority'      => 'high'
);
```

Also look at *Table 2a* in the documentation for [Notification payload support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json). `message` is not supported, use `body` instead.

```
$msg = array
(
    'body'      => 'here is a message. message', // <= CHANGED
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I left it as gcm (since fcm was giving me 404 error for some reason), but after changing it to notification it works to some extent. I was able to verify that the topic is working, however oddly I am only getting the sound of the notification.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much Bob.